# Is the space $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ of continuous maps on $S^1$ compact? (Compact-open topology)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Is the space $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ of continuous maps $S^1\to S^1$ compact? Here $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ has the compact-open topology.

I'm not too savvy with the compact-open topology so I'm not sure where to really begin. I also tried searching this question and couldn't find it on here. I know that $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ has a prebasis (subbasis) given by all
$$
S(K,U):=\{f:S^1\to S^1\mid f(K)\subseteq U\}
$$
where $K\subseteq S^1$ is compact and $U\subseteq S^1$ is open. But I don't know how to relate this to the compactness of $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)$. Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried leveraging the fact that $S^1$ is itself compact?

Comment: Kinda: if we start with an open cover $\text{Map}(S^1,S^1)=\bigcup_{a\in I}U_a$, each $U_a$ can be written as a union of a finite intersection of the $S(K,U)$. Now each constant map is continuous, so there has to be enough $S(K,U)$ belonging to $\bigcup_{a\in I}U_a$ so that the codomain $S^1$ gets covered by open sets $U$, from which we could extract a finite subcover via the compactness of $S^1$. But then I don't see how to build a finite subcover of $\bigcup_{a\in I}U_a$ out of this..

Comment: By Arzela-Ascoli it suffices to prove equicontinuity and that $\{f(y) : f\in \text{Maps}(S^1, S^1)\}$ is relatively compact for all $y$

Comment: After googling Arzela-Ascoli, I see how that approach could work, but I was hoping for a more direct, less analytical approach...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space $\operatorname{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ is not compact. To see this, we can use the following well-known theorems:

1. If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $(Y,d)$ is a metric space, then the compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ agrees with the metric topology induced by the supremum metric $d(f,g) = \sup\{d(f(x),g(x)) \mid x \in X \}$.
   See for example [Topology on the set of Continuous Functions from a Compact to a Metric Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3620490).
2. Each compact metric space is sequentially compact (which means that each sequence has a convergent subsequence).
   See fort example [In a metric space, compact implies sequentially compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3751394).

Now assume that $\operatorname{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ is compact. Consider the sequence $f_n(z) = e^{i\lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) \rvert^n}$ (recall $S^1  = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert z \rvert = 1\\$). It must have a convergent subsequence (with respect to the supremum metric) $(f_{n_k})$ with limit $f \in \operatorname{Map}(S^1,S^1)$. Clearly $f$ is also the pointwise limit of this sequence.

For $z \ne \pm 1$ we have $\lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) \rvert < 1$, hence $\lim_{k \to \infty}\lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) \rvert^{n_k} = 0$ and therefore $f(z)  = \lim_{k \to \infty}f_{n_k}(z) = e^{i0} = e^0 = 1$. For $z = \pm 1$  we have $\lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) \rvert = 1$, hence $\lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) \rvert^{n_k} = 1$ for all $k$ and therefore $f(\pm1) = e^{i1} = e^i \ne 1$.
This shows that $f$ is not continuous which contradicts $f \in \operatorname{Map}(S^1,S^1)$.

Therefore $\operatorname{Map}(S^1,S^1)$ is not compact.

**Remark:**

The compactness of a function space $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ enforces serious requirements concerning $X, Y$. Here are two fairly obvious results:

1. If $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$  is compact and $X \ne \emptyset$, then $Y$ is compact.
   In fact, let  $\mathfrak U$ be an open cover of $Y$. Pick $x \in X$. Then the sets $S(\{x\},U)$ with $U \in \mathfrak U$ form an open cover of $C_{co}(X,Y)$. If this space is compact, then there exist finitely many $U_i \in \mathfrak U$ such that the $S(\{x\},U_i)$ cover $C_{co}(X,Y)$. Thus for each $y \in Y$ the constant functions $c_y :  X \to Y$ with value $y$ is contained in some $S(\{x\},U_i)$. But then $y = c_y(x) \in U_i$. Therefore the $U_i$ cover $Y$.
2. If $Y$ is compact and $X$ is discrete, then $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ is compact.
   In fact, for a discrete $X$ we have $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y) \approx \prod_{x \in X} \operatorname{Map}(\{x\},Y)$ which is a product of compact spaces since $\operatorname{Map}(\{x\},Y) \approx Y$.

Exercise 3.4.F in

> Engelking, Ryszard. "General topology." (1977)

gives further clarification and shows that 2. is not that far from a complete solution as one might think:

3. If $X$ is Tychonoff space (= completely regular Hausdorff space)
   and $Y$  contains a subspace homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then  $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ is compact if and only if $Y$ is compact and and $X$ is discrete.

Another useful theorem in this context is the general *Ascoli Theorem* as stated in Theorems 3.4.20 and 3.4.21 in Engelking's book. It gives us the following corollary:

Let $X$ be a $k$-space and $Y$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ is compact if and only $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ is [evenly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an open cover that has no finite subcover. Let $U := (-1/3, 1/3)$ and $V := (1/6, 5/6)$ (I'm thinking of $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). Then $\mathrm{Map}(S^1, S^1)$ is covered by the open sets
$$
\{S([-1/k, 1/k], U) \,|\, k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{S(\{0\}, V)\},
$$
since a map $S^1 \to S^1$ must take 0 into either $U$ or $V$, and if it takes 0 into $U$, then being continuous it takes an interval surrounding 0 into $U$.

To see that this cover has no finite subcover, fix a finite collection of these open sets and let $K$ be the maximum value such that $S([-1/K, 1/K], U)$ is one of those finitely many open sets. There are continuous functions $f : S^1 \to S^1$ such that $f(0) = 0 \in U$ but $f([-1/K, 1/K]) \nsubseteq U$, and such functions are not contained in the union of these finitely many open sets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\text{Cl}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$ be the (discrete) space of conjugacy classes of elements of $\pi_{1}\left(S^{1}\right)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ (so just $\mathbb{Z}$ itself...). The natural map $$\pi_{1}\ \colon\ \text{Map}\left(S^{1},S^{1}\right)\to\text{Cl}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$$ is continuous with non-compact image, so with non-compact domain.

(The map is continuous because the unbased loop space of $S^{1}$ is locally path connected. I.e., for a given unbased loop in $S^{1}$, there is a finite collection of compact-open mapping relationships satisfied by that unbased loop which together determine the conjugacy class in $\pi_{1}\left(S^{1}\right)$ induced by any unbased loop in $S^{1}$ that satisfies them.)

Answer (score -1):

If it were we would not need [Arzelà-Ascoli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).

Here is an example from with a closely related space $I=[0,1]$. The sequence of function $f_n(x) = x^n$ has no convergent sub-sequence.

$\bf{Added:}$ We can adapt the above example to $S^1$. Consider the sequence of continuous functions $f_n \colon S^1 \to S^1$ with no convergent subsequence $$f_n(e^{2 \pi i t}) = e^{2 \pi i t^n}$$
($t\in [0,1]$)